# Parsing XML Pastebin response, in Python

Tags: python, xml, pastebin

I'm trying to search for something on Pastebin, via their API. I'm searching using the pastebin library for python.

The problem is that I receive an XML response, that has repeating keys.

This is the response

```
<paste>
<paste_key>fadsda</paste_key>
<paste_date>1409074286</paste_date>
<paste_title>badPaste</paste_title>
<paste_size>2040</paste_size>
<paste_expire_date>0</paste_expire_date>
<paste_private>0</paste_private>
<paste_format_long>Bash</paste_format_long>
<paste_format_short>bash</paste_format_short>
<paste_url>http://pastebin.com/url2</paste_url>
<paste_hits>211</paste_hits>
</paste>
<paste>
<paste_key>fsfgdsgg</paste_key>
<paste_date>1398409838</paste_date>
<paste_title>goodPaste</paste_title>
<paste_size>2407</paste_size>
<paste_expire_date>0</paste_expire_date>
<paste_private>2</paste_private>
<paste_format_long>Bash</paste_format_long>
<paste_format_short>bash</paste_format_short>
<paste_url>http://pastebin.com/otherURL</paste_url>
<paste_hits>54</paste_hits>
</paste>
```

So I am trying to parse it to return `paste_key` when `paste_title == goodPaste`, but the attrib is always empty

```
def parseXML(response):
    #I'm adding a root tag
    xml = ElementTree.fromstring('<list>' + response + '</list>')
    for child in root:
            for elem in child:
                print elem.tag, elem.attrib
```

returns

```
    paste_key {}
    paste_date {}
    paste_title {}
    paste_size {}
    paste_expire_date {}
    paste_private {}
    paste_format_long {}
    paste_format_short {}
    paste_url {}
    paste_hits {}
    paste_key {}
    paste_date {}
    paste_title {}
    paste_size {}
    paste_expire_date {}
    paste_private {}
    paste_format_long {}
    paste_format_short {}
    paste_url {}
    paste_hits {}
```

**EDIT**:
So I was supposed to use elem.text, so that's working now, but the main question still exists: 
How can I return the element where `paste_key` when `paste_title == goodPaste`

**EDIT 2**
Winning ticket:

```
result = xml.findall(".//paste[paste_title='goodPaste']/paste_key")
print result[0].text
```

Comment: Thats because there is no attributes to what you're showing, only tag data. The way you access it is by saying `.text` not `.attrib`

Comment: @JavierBuzzi you are a genius! thank you! I missunderstood the ElementTree docs. Thank you, again!

Comment: Np. here are the docs if you get lost. https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text

Comment: @JavierBuzzi post as answer thus he can close the question plz.

Comment: @AliNikneshan please check the post, that is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XPath for that:

```
result = xml.findall(".//paste[paste_title='goodPaste']/paste_key")
print result.text
```

This should print `fsfgdsgg` in your case

Comment: It worked, but for clarity, `result` is a list, so I'm printing `result[0].text`.
thank you!